# Query updates all of my data instead of only the one I want

Tags: c#, database

How do I make it so that my query only update the data I want?

Here's the current code

```
string query = string.Format("update Customer set title='{0}',[Name]='{1}'",titleComboBox2.Text,nameTextBox2.Text,"where ID="+idTextBox+"");
```

Apparently the last part of the query isn't working. Why it is that?

Comment: What is the data you're dealing with, what is happening, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't use any index argument as `{2}` for your third argument which is `WHERE` part.

That's why your query will be contain only `update Customer set title='{0}',[Name]='{1}'` part this will be update for your all rows since it doesn't have any filter.

Fun fact, you could see *this* as `query` if you would debug your code.

#### But more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Let's assume you use ADO.NET;

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"update Customer set title = @title, [Name] = @name 
                       where ID = @id";
   cmd.Paramter.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = titleComboBox2.Text;
   cmd.Paramter.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = nameTextBox2.Text;
   cmd.Paramter.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(idTextBox.Text);
   // I assumed your column types.
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: How do I check if I'm using ADO.NET or not?

Comment: I think I'm using OleDb. What should I do?

Comment: @huehuehue Then use `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` instead of `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your query does not use `WHERE` clause, because it is ignored by `string.Format`. You have 3 placeholder parameters, and you are using only `{0}` and `{1}`, so `WHERE` part is never added to the SQL query. Change your query to include `WHERE` clause, e.g. like this:

```
string query = string.Format("update Customer set title='{0}',[Name]='{1}' {2}",titleComboBox2.Text,nameTextBox2.Text,"where ID="+idTextBox.Text+"");
```

However, there is one very serious flaw in your code - it is vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are hundreds of articles about it online, make sure to read about what that is and how to update your code accordingly (hint - parametrize queries)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Tried using the code and a syntax error pops out. Why is it that?

Comment: @huehuehue Most likely because `idTextBox` is a textbox, so you need to use `idTextBox.Text` instead. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. As for the flaw, is it okay for me to ignore it if I'm only coding for a school project?

Comment: @huehuehue SQL injection attacks are potentially disastrous. The sooner you start using code in the right way the better it is.

Comment: That is something you can't ignore. Teacher, reading your project should give you a score of zero if you ignore it.